# How to select NaN cells in a dataframe?

Tags: python, database, pandas, pycharm

In the table below, how can I print out the corresponding "Schedule" value of every NaN element under the "Type" column ?

```
   Section Type               Schedule Location
0       A1  LEC    MWF 1:25 pm-2:15 pm  STO B50
1       A1  NaN      R 6:30 pm-8:30 pm     ROOM
2       A2  LEC   MWF 12:20 pm-1:10 pm  STO B50
3       A2  NaN      R 6:30 pm-8:30 pm     ROOM
4       A3  LEC    TR 12:30 pm-1:45 pm  STO B50
5       A3  NaN      R 6:30 pm-8:30 pm     ROOM
6       B1  DIS      T 2:00 pm-3:15 pm  EPC 207
7       B2  DIS      T 3:30 pm-4:45 pm  EPC 207
8       B3  DIS      T 5:00 pm-6:15 pm  EPC 207
9       B4  DIS      R 2:00 pm-3:15 pm  EPC 207
10      B5  DIS      M 2:30 pm-3:45 pm  CAS 324
11      B6  DIS      W 2:30 pm-3:45 pm  CAS 324
12      B7  DIS      R 3:30 pm-4:45 pm  EPC 207
13     SA1  IND   MTWR 1:00 pm-3:00 pm  MCS B29
14     SA2  IND    MTR 6:00 pm-8:30 pm  COM 217
15     SB1  IND  MTWR 11:00 am-1:00 pm  PSY B51
16     SB2  IND    MTR 6:00 pm-8:30 pm  PSY B37
17      A1  LEC  MWF 11:15 am-12:05 pm      STO
18      A1  NaN      R 6:30 pm-8:30 pm      NaN
19      A2  LEC    MWF 2:30 pm-3:20 pm      STO
20      A2  NaN      R 6:30 pm-8:30 pm      NaN
21      A3  LEC     TR 8:00 am-9:15 am      STO
22      A3  NaN      R 6:30 pm-8:30 pm      NaN
23      B1  DIS      M 4:30 pm-5:45 pm      NaN
24      B2  DIS     T 12:30 pm-1:45 pm      NaN
25      B3  DIS      T 3:30 pm-4:45 pm      NaN
26      B4  DIS      W 8:30 am-9:45 am      CAS
27      B5  DIS      W 4:30 pm-5:45 pm      NaN
28      B6  DIS     R 12:30 pm-1:45 pm      NaN
```

```
for v in length:
    string_v = str(v)
    if d.loc[string_v, "Type"] == ? :
        print(d.loc[string_v, "Schedule"])
```

I do not know what to equate the d.loc[string_v, "Type"] to. I have tried the empty string ''

I have also tried 'NaN'. I looked into the html page source and it says that that specific cell is equal to $0. So I thought that I could equate it to '$0' but that does not work either.

What is the value of the NaN cells?

Comment: In order to try it out, can we have full source code?

Answer (score 0):

I have a hard time to simulate your case. Please, include a **complete** code so everyone can easily simulate your case.

From your question, you are trying to detect NaN.

numpy.isnan(), return result as a bool array.

Refer to the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = ['A1', np.NaN, 'MWF', '11:15 am-12:05 pm', 'STO']
b = ['A1', 'LEC', 'MWF', '11:15 am-12:05 pm', 'STO']

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(a, b)), columns =['Name', 'val'])
print(df)

for v, row in df.iterrows():
    # print(df.loc[v, 'Name'])
    try:
        if np.isnan(df.loc[v, 'Name']):
            print(df.loc[v, "val"])
    except:
        print("")
```